# What's going to happend with these pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I've seen some code that I can't figure out exactly what's going on there, the piece of code is: I got char *s1, char *s2 from the function, and they've done this:

```
*s1 = *s2;
```

What's going on behind the sence with this? (in C, asci-c)

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ScottHunter I did, and I can't understand what's going on behind the sence.

Comment: It's going to copy a char from (wherever s2 points to), to (wherever s1 points to).

Comment: @Twisty Thank you, I would keep that in mind for next time

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I got that, but why?

Comment: Because that's how C's syntax is defined:  if you have a pointer p, then *p is the syntax for dereferencing the pointer (i.e. referring to whatever it is the pointer is currently pointing to).  And = is the assignment operator, which copies from the item on the right, to the item on the left.

Comment: @idolevi This must be explained in your C textbook or tutorial, in the chapter on pointers. It's the most basic thing about them.

Comment: If you have a question about "what's going on behind the scenes" and you want the real answer, you need to look at what the compiler produces.  Go to the [godbolt](http://godbolt.org) compiler explorer and enter the function `int test(char *s1, char *s2) {*s1 = *s2;}`.  If you enter in the compiler options `-O2` then you might see something like `mov al, BYTE PTR [rsi]` and `mov BYTE PTR [rdi], al`.  This is the only meaningful answer to your question...what's going on behind the scenes is that the compiler is emitting instructions to accomplish what the language spec says it should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C and C++ `*` can be used with the pointer of a variable to access and assign its value.

Here:

```
*s1 = *s2;
```

`*s2` is accessing the value of the variable that is pointed by `s2` pointer and then assigning this value to the variable that is pointed by `s1`. While `=` is an assignment operator used to assign a value to a variable.

Please visit [this site](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) for complete reference.